# Javascript auto count on 30 days and delete data from table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, html-framework-7

[mysql table structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3H9q.png)

I would like to let the table data delete after 30 days count from current date.

above is mysql database structure screenshot (I use current timestamp for date)

and this is the code I used to select all the data from customers table

```
$$(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-name="home_employee"]', function(e) {

    console.log('this is page employee');

    var sqlget = 'SELECT * FROM `customers`';

    //this is select the data from customers [emplotee_table (home_employee.html)]
    connection.query(sqlget, function(error, results, fields) {


        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            $$(document).find('#employee_table').append($$('<tr data-id="' + results[i].id + '"> ' +
                '<td class="checkbox-cell">' +
                '<label class="checkbox">' +
                '<input type="checkbox">' +
                '<i class="icon-checkbox"></i>' +
                '</label>' +
                '</td>' +
                ' <td style="font-family:Poppins-Medium;" class="label-cell"> ' + results[i].name + ' </td>' +
                ' <td class="numeric-cell">' + results[i].telephone + '</td> ' +
                ' <td class="numeric-cell">' + results[i].order_num + '</td> ' +
                '<td class="numeric-cell">' + results[i].juice1_num + '</td> ' +
                '<td class="numeric-cell">' + results[i].juice2_num + '</td> ' +
                '<td class="numeric-cell">' + results[i].juice3_num + '</td> ' +
                '<td class="numeric-cell">' + results[i].date + '</td> ' +
                '</tr>'));
        }
    });

});
```

[table screenshot at here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jh3n.png)

How I make javascript count the timestamp? or is that I need to change mysql structure to get this done?

Comment: You can compare dates using `Date` object. Regarding deleting data you can use `array.filter`. Something like: `var maxDate = new Date(); maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 30); var filteredResult = results.filter((result) => +new Date(result.date) < +maxDate)`. But to give you a concrete answer, I would need sample data as well

Comment: so how do I give you a sample data

Comment: you can try my above suggestion. If it doesn't work, we can look deeper with a working sample

Comment: check my answer , I think it's can done what I want to , or maybe you can give me some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I done it by using some tricks

```
var sqldeletetime = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE date < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)";

    connection.query(sqldeletetime, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("delete every record pass 30 days");
    });
```